# Can't flash OTA file using TeamWin Recovery on HTC One

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, ota-update, htc-one

I have HTC One, with custom recovery, bootloader unlocked, and rooted.

I got the OTA by from Settings - Software Update. After downloading, I wanted to flash the ZIP file in Recovery mode. But when I want to flash that, after 5 or 6 seconds, it says failed because MD5 can't be found. I already downloaded this file 2 times because I thought the file has problem, but the file seems to be okay.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There's a "file integrity check" involved with the flash process, to prevent broken/tampered files from being flashed. Basically, you've got 3 options:

1. Get the `.md5` file that should go along the `.zip`
2. [generate the `.md5` yourself](http://androidforums.com/threads/md5-verification.443074/) (if you cannot find it, ***and are sure your `.zip` is fine***)
3. Turning off verification in TWRP.

Btw: There was a [discussion at AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/lg-optimus-s/224952-md5.html) on this topic, which you might wish to check.